# How many primitives can I draw using Canvas in Android with Hardware Acceleration Layer enabled?

Tags: android-canvas

Is there hardware limitation to draw *Rect*, *Line*, *Point* etc per frame? I know Android uses a texture mask to draw a shape but no other info exists.